# What is the best mobile keyboard for alphanumeric input type?

Tags: mobile, keyboard

I need to set the most user-friendly keyboard for anyone who enters his car's license plate number.

In the country I develop for, those are alphanumeric. There are other countries that use numbers only for license plate.

I looked into my platform's [visual guide to keyboard type options](http://lefkowitz.me/2018/04/30/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/) and nothing satisfies my need.

Although I'm fast on my mobile keyboard, I find it very annoying when entering `WW1E1E`, which is a valid license plate number.

I can only imagine the frustration of somebody unexperienced who needs to toggle alpha and numeric up to 4 times while typing 6-characters long string.

Left side is iOS, right side is Android. Although the `visible-password` keyboard is OK, it does not **currently** work with automatic capitalization (`autoCapitalize="characters"`, to capitalize all characters typed), and is overall hacky, I guess.

Here is a collection of all the available keyboard types currently on React **Native v0.55 on iOS 11 and Android 8.**

Which keyboard type should I go with?

[image]

Comment: Not helpful for answering the question, but I wonder why no platform apparently has a _calculator_ numeric pad layout

Comment: @Crissov I suspect because hese are fundamentally **phones**. So the standard phone numeric keypad needs to be included for dialing and therefore gets used everywhere else (i.e., no "calculator" option) that a "keyboard" is used, whether for a calculator application, a web page (e.g., numeric input which might be a phone number but might be ordinary numbers), etc. But at least on a couple of Android apps I just checked, the apps use a calculator style keyboard by **not** using a "keyboard" reference but instead building a clearly different page of their own specific buttons for everything.

Comment: Would it be an affordable option to design your own keyboard modally popping up, with precisely the signs needed?

Comment: @peter_the_oak sure it would, the question is: is it user-friendly, doesn't it throw the user off when he sees something new while expecting good old keyboard?

Comment: @wscourge This is in fact an important question. I checked out for myself what I would expect in my "reflexes". In my opinion, if the new keyboard would have basically a very similar behaviour, e.g. appear at the bottom, and if it was clear enough, I would accept it. - On the other side, use your own argument: If users are so accustomed to "good old keyboard", then they could live with switching four times between numbers and letters, as they have learnt this. As I have learnt - every time I enter a password. For I use strong passwords, I must always switch to reach some punctuation marks.

Comment: @peter_the_oak I see your point, therefore I will just use the default keyboard, you pretty much nailed it with _they could live with switching four times between numbers and letters, as they have learned this_. Thanks for your input.

Comment: `I don't know any country where they're not [alphanumeric]` - They are numeric-only in Israel, and presumably anywhere which uses a non-Latin-or-similar alphabet

Comment: Also, some keyboards have a "number keys" option, which add the numeric row to the top (like my Galaxy S7). So a user who's bothered enough with the lack of number keys (like me) can turn it on anyways - another plus for keeping the default keyboard.

Comment: @wscourge I am not sure i understand what you mean by: "Android (where visible-password is OK but does not work with automatic capitalization"

Comment: asking regarding the part you say it does not work with Automatic capitalization

Comment: How Android (visible-password) does not work with Automatic Capitalization? It does capitalize the first letter of the statements.

Comment: @Mo'ath it is React Native I'm talking about, and it's exactly `autoCapitalize="characters"` that does not work for me. Why would I want only the first letter capitalized if all characters in the license plate are upper case?

Comment: It is good to know which value of autoCapitalization is not working with you. This could be a current bug in react native that will be fixed at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The keyboard with the numbers row on top!

Whether it is the visible-password keyboard, or default keyboard that has the numbers row added to the top (enabled by default), what matters is having the **numbers row added.**

*I do not think the visible-password keyboard is hacky. Just an opinion.*

**Take these scenarios:**

1- Numbers row is added and `autoCapitalize ="characters"` is working:

There is no doubt that this keyboard will be the fastest among the ones you provided. It will take **8 taps** to input the 6-character string "WW1E1E". The extra 2 taps are to activate capitalizing all characters.

2- Numbers row is added BUT `autoCapitalize = "characters"` is not working:

It will take **9 taps** to input the 6-character string "WW1E1E".

*Remember that the `autoCapitalize="characters"` issue with visible-password keyboard is a **temporary bug** that if there is no way around it now, it will be fixed with an update.*

3- NO numbers row, but `autoCapitalize ="characters"` is working:

It will take **12 taps!** to input the 6-character string "WW1E1E". **Or longer time** if you choose to hold the top row keys instead of toggling back and forth between alphabets and numbers.

---

**Notes:**

- If we compare two keyboards, both have *autoCapitalizing* working, but one with the numbers row added, and the other without it, as long as your string is alphanumeric, **you will always need more taps or time when using a no-numbers-row keyboard!**
- I used the string you provided "WW1E1E" as an example to calculate the number of taps having in mind that other strings like "WWW111" could result in only one extra tap using no-numbers-row keyboard.
- `autoCapitalize = "characters"` gets usually enabled by users when double tapping the shift key on the mobile keyboard (2 taps).

Comment: Thanks for your time, although there are is a problem on the iPhone - no such keyboard. Also, I strongly agreed with @peter_the_oak in the comments under the question and will go for the _default_ keyboard instead.

Comment: Sure, it is your decision. Different people think differently, that's a beauty! However, I do not agree with the approach that people could live with it (switching four times between numbers and letters). Our goal is improve and create a better user experience. I find that the numbers row feature is mainly the reason the android keyboard is better than the iphone.

Comment: It's not about what's better, it's about supporting both

Comment: I understand that iphone does not have that keyboard. But they (ios and android) will have two different keyboards anyway. So I do not see the point of consistency if that what you are trying to achieve. iphone does not support it (a limitation), android supports it (an advantage). I won't prevent android users from having a better keyboard because iphone does not support it. And if it is for consistency, then again they are going to use two different keyboards anyway...

Answer (score 2):

If it is alphanumeric, it has to be the default keyboard. Uppercase letters should not be a concern because the text input can be coded to accept all alphabetical characters as Uppercase which will allow the users to enter alphabets in lower case without having to toggle Uppercase every time.

One way to provide explicit numeric or alphabetic keypads would be to break down the number into multiple smaller inputs as per the country license format. For example, if the number is XX-00-000, then have three input boxes where XX is pure alphabetic and the rest two numeric.